# Get all the Ti.API.info strings to an array

Tags: console, titanium

I need to get all the Ti.API.info strings to an array by using some function at the end of the app.js file, How do I get all those string to array once it has been printed on console. For Example

```
Ti.API.info("Hello");
Ti.API.info("Good Morning");
Ti.API.info("Good Afternoon");
Ti.API.info("Good Evening");
```

at the end of the code I need to have an function to retrieve and store all the strings in array. How do I can do that, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the existing Ti.API.info function, but, this **isn't highly recommended** as people might not know that you changed it (even if changes made doesn't impact the initial behavior).

I think that the best way is to define your own logger.

**customLogger.js**

```
var Logger = function () {
    /* Define an array to store logs */   
    this._logs = [];
}

Logger.prototype.info = function () {
    /* Iterate over each msg and store them */
    for(var i = 0, msg; msg = arguments[i]; i++) {
        this._logs.push({date: new Date(), msg: msg.toString()});          
    }

    /* Do the classic log */
    Ti.API.info.apply(Ti.API, arguments);
}

Logger.prototype.getLogs = function () {
    return JSON.stringify(this._logs, null, "\t");
}

/* Export The API */
var logger = new Logger(Ti.API);
exports.info = function() {
    Logger.prototype.info.apply(logger, arguments);
};

exports.getLogs = function () {
    return Logger.prototype.getLogs.apply(logger);
};
```

Then, in your **app.js**

```
var Logger = require("customLogger"); // Adapt the path to suits your architecture

Logger.info("My log message");

// ...

Ti.API.debug("Those are my logs:\n", Logger.getLogs());
```

Comment: If it works and solves your problem, do not hesitate to mark the question as answered :)